# Selecting * from table returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this php script that allows me to fetch all the rows in a table in my MySQL database.
I have put the `echo "1"`, etc. to see whether it gets to the code at the very end. The output proves it does. However, it does not output anything when echoing `json_encode($resultsArray)`, which I can't seem to figure out why.

**Code:**

```
// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx");
// Check connection
if (!$connection) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); } else { echo "0"; }

// select database
if (!mysqli_select_db($connection, "myDB")) { die('Unable to connect to database. '. mysqli_connect_error()); } else { echo "1"; }

$sql = "select * from myTable";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));;
echo "3";

$resultsArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// convert to array
    $resultsArray[] = $row;
}
echo "4";
// return array w/ contents
echo json_encode($resultsArray);
echo "5";
```

**Output:**

```
01345
```

I figured, it is not about the `json_encode`, because I can also try to echo sth. like `$result['id']` inside the while loop and it just won't do anything.

For testing, I went into the database using Terminal. I can do `select * from myTable` without any issues.

Any idea?

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: `{ echo "query failed"; }` that won't help in case of a query failure, check for the real error. Do that, then update your post.

Comment: Doesn't really matter b/c it doesn't even fail. Technically you're right, though @Fred-ii-

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned all the way up so you're seeing any notices issued? At the top of this script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.  You can also verify `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to see if it matches what you expect.

Comment: You call `mysqli_query()` twice. Under certain circumstances (though I don't think this is one of them) if you execute a new query without fully fetching rows from the previous one, it will fail. If I recall that should only happen with something like a stored procedure execution, but `display_errors` will make it clearer if that has happened.

Comment: Any chance that your table is actually empty? Or that you are selecting a different database/connection/environment than you think you are?

Comment: ^^ (we see that sort of problem far more often than you'd expect)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I put the code you gave me at the top of my script, but I can't see any errors. Also, I tried calling `mysqli_query()` once or twice, it made no difference. And nope, the table has a few columns and 3 rows, all completely filled as I can see in terminal.

Comment: oh that's why you're getting the "1" here, as @MichaelBerkowski said; I should have noticed that, you're querying twice. That's what's going on here. That "1" isn't coming from `else { echo "1"; }`.

Comment: So I changed the double-querying to the `die` thingy. No change.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth In that case, test if `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` is zero, your table really is empty - & perhaps you're connected to the wrong version of your database.

Comment: It says `3`, @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Funny thing is, it used to work like half an hour ago. In the meantime I changed the value types of 2 columns by dropping and re-adding them. Might that have sth. to do w/ this?

Comment: Check `json_get_last_error_msg()` and also `var_dump($row)` inside your fetch loop.

Comment: Uhh it said fatal error for `json_get_last_error_msg()` so I put `json_last_error_msg()` instead (which PhpStorm suggested) but there's no error message displayed.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` prints the contents from the table and some gibberish... (yay?)

Comment: Any idea how I can solve this, @MichaelBerkowski?

Comment: Gibberish? Other than the array element types and structure?  If `$row` has values, does `var_dump($resultsArray);` have a 2D array structure (it should)? Store the return from json_encode into a variable then `var_dump($thatvariable)`. It must return a string, or FALSE, and if FALSE, than `json_last_error_msg()` should have some details (called after json_encode())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157208/discussion-between-linusgeffarth-and-michael-berkowski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After around 20hrs of debugging, I figured out the issue.

As I stated in my question, the code used to work a few hours before posting this question and then suddenly stopped working. @MichaelBerkowski confirmed that the code is functional.
I remembered that at some point, I altered my columns to have a default value of an empty string - I declared them as follows: `columnName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`.
I now found that replicating the table and leaving out the `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` part makes `json_encode()` work again, so apparently there's an issue with that.

Thanks to everybody for trying anyway!